# Moving the project's repository to another server

Tags: svn

my client changes the server so there is a necessity to move the whole repository. Both servers are running on Windows. I want to have the whole copy (+ the whole changes history) of the repository from the server admin. Do I only need the repository dump file or maybe there is something else also needed ?

### Edit

Is it possible to do that without the admin access to the server storing the SVN ?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the repository dump is the best way in which you can preserve the whole changes and history, other methods of moving will keep your latest changes but the old history will be lost. The best practice is to get the dump of the current repository and import the dump in the new server.

Comment: I've found the rsvndump project to do the dump file (http://blog.sourcehosting.net/2008/11/03/dump-remote-subversion-repository/) Do You know if it include the whole project history ?